# When git commit, appears "The file has been changed since reading it!!!"

Tags: linux, git, vmware

I use VMware under windows, and centos6.5 is the virtual machine. I use VMTools share folder between windows and centos.  I use centos git in the share folder, However, when I git commit, it appears this message. Details as the image[image]

I use centos git in the folder that is not shared, there is no this warning message.
I use windows git int share folder and not shared folder, there are both no this warning messege.
What can I do to avoid this warning message.

Comment: If you remove Git from equation and just open given text editor in the shared folder, will it produce the same warning message?

Comment: I restart the centos, the problem resolved........